# UIBarButtonItem Taking Entire Width of UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, width, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem` that I created in Interface Builder. The `UIBarButtonItem` is a bordered button that contains a custom image.

The button takes up the entire length of the toolbar. I have tried using different images, changing the width of the button... I don't know what else to do. It stretches across the entire toolbar.

If I use one the provided "Identifiers" (camera, trash, compose...) the button appears a normal size.

[image: How it looks in Interface Builder]

How it looks in Interface Builder

[image: How it looks when I run it on the iPhone]

How it looks when I run it on the iPhone

#### SOLUTION

After some more tinkering, here is what I found: if I create a new UIToolbar and add custom image to the UIBarButtonItem, it works fine - but as soon as I connect the UIBarButtonItem to an IBOutlet, it goes large. I had to then specify the UIBarButtonItem's width in the code, via the IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I think it might have to do with how the frame is defined in the "sizing inspector", could you maybe show a screenshot of the settings?

Comment: All the values are zero. Does not change if I change the values.

Comment: What about the autosizing settings? The two squares with the red bars on each side.

Comment: There are no autosizing setting for UIBarButtonItem. Just width, and image inset top/bottom/left/right.

Comment: I have just created a sample and will post some screenshots for you.

Comment: It did not allow me to upload my images. So I will give you the settings verbally: **UIToolBar:** Frame Rectangle, X=0 Y=436, Width=320 Height=44, Autosizing: left, bottom, right and width are selected. Arrange: Position View. **UIBarButtonItem:** Everything is set to 0

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I have... this is on a Camera Overlay, I am beginning to thing that has something to do with it.

Comment: Ooook. I deleted the UIToolbar and added a new one, and now the button appears as expected. Seems I was chasing my tail. Sorry and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace on the right of the camera bordered item.